# incompatible compilation error built-in function ‘execl’

Tags: c

I am compiling crashme source code on windows using cywin and i am facing some compilation error.

Error:

```
crashme.c: In function 'vfork_main':
crashme.c:594: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘execl’
```

Though the source code had unistd.h included, but still the error persisting. Kindly help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Probably a missing `#include` of the *"system"* header defining `execl` (i.e. `<unistd.h>` on Linux).

To find out what is included, use `gcc -H -c foo.c` and use `gcc -C -E -Wall foo.c > foo.i` to get the preprocessed form.

Comment: Get the preprocessed form as explained above, and look into it (search for `execl` there).

Comment: @user1031345 Wait, by checking under /usr/include do you mean that the header is in that directory or that you've checked that your _code_ `#include`s that header?

Comment: I've just checked for the header file is there or not. BTW, i didn't get any information from the preprocessed output while searching for execl.

Comment: if declaration of `execl` don't appear in `foo.i` where expected as generated above, it means that you have some `#include` issues (perhaps typos on some `#ifdef` ???)

Comment: This is how ifdef got declared

Comment: It is not a declaration, and preprocessor directives like `#ifdef` and `#include` should all appear on a different line.

Comment: Yes, those are declared in different lines. I am compiling a program called crashme located at (http://people.delphiforums.com/gjc/crashme.zip) for testing some kernal patches.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch - Can you tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The source *doesn't* have `unistd.h` included.

I wasn't able to open `crashme.zip`, but I was able to *partially* unpack `crashme.tgz`.

`crashme.c` has the following (lines 150-152):

```
#ifdef linux
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

You're compiling on Cygwin, which is *not* a Linux system, so of course the symbol `linux` is not defined.  As a result, the `#include <unistd.h>` is skipped.

That's surprising, since `<unistd.h>` should be available on all Unix-like (i.e., POSIX) systems, not just Linux -- and comments in the source indicate that it's been used on SunOS 4.1.1 and several other Unix systems.

Commenting out the `#ifdef linux` and `#endif` lines should fix the immediate problem, but I have no idea what other problems might be lurking behind it.  It's going to take some unknown amount of effort to get this working under Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks Thomspson, I will try to compile by un commenting ifdef/endif lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently updated http://crashme.codeplex.com/ source code to work on Mac OS X Lion with Xcode command line tools, with changes to make it more potent on 64-bit x64 architectures. But under Windows I would suggest using the native windows port instead of cygwin, using the pre-compiled windows installer msi file. You can report bugs/issues on the codeplex site.